# Populate Excel table with new data while keeping historic data

Tags: excel, vba, macos, excel-formula

This is based on Excel 2016 for Mac.

**Short primer:**
I run a report every week which consists of a table with statistical ticket data. One of the columns in table 1 is the 'customer name', to which I also want the subsidiary. In order to do so I have a second table.

Table 2 has these columns:

```
| Contract Number | Subsidiary | Customer Name | Start Date | End Date   |
```

With this I use a simple vlookup in order to match the subsidiary to the customer name. This works fine. Table 2 occasionally needs updating as new contracts are being added to the data, however I also want to keep the old records to be able to also match contracts which are already expired (historical data).

**What I want** is to be able to use a list of new contract data (I can get this in CSV or also Excel) (let's call this table 3) and then have table 2 updated with new entries, while not changing the old ones. To identify contracts which are already in table 2 I can use the contract number, as it is unique.

*Example*
Table 2 consists of two entries

```
Line | Contract Number | Subsidiary | Customer Name | Start Date | End Date   |    
1    | 123456          | Sub 1      | Cust 1        | 2018-01-01 | 2018-12-31 |    
2    | 7890123         | Sub 2      | Cust 2        | 2018-05-01 | 2019-04-30 |
```

Now when I pull new data today I would get the second entry and a new third one, but not the first entry, as the end date is already in the past. Sadly I can't just pull the data for say 3 years, as I will only get active contracts.

*Table 3 example*

```
2    | 7890123         | Sub 2      | Cust 2        | 2018-05-01 | 2019-04-30 |   
3    | 555555          | Sub 3      | Cust 3        | 2019-01-05 | 2020-01-04 |
```

I now would like to add line three to table 2, while keeping line 1 in table 2 and not changing line 2.

Comment: *"I now would like to add line three to table 2"* Which is line 3? Which are the criteria used to choose the lines that have to be copied? What code do you have so far (please [edit] and include in your question). • Alternative idea: Filter and copy all "historical" lines to table 3 instead might be easier?

Comment: I've changed the text above and put line numbers in there.
So far I have been doing the updates of this table manually, as this only needs to be done every couple of weeks. But would like to automate this in the future.
Your alternative I will check if it is usable. Thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: Note that this website is no free coding service so you should at least come up with something you have already tried and show where you got stuck or errors. Also we need a concrete question to answer (you didn't ask one yet, you just posted a set of requirements). • Another idea could be, remove all lines in table 2 with a non-historical end date (so only historical data remains) and push **all** the data from table 3 into table 2. Give it a try.